# Сортировка двумерного массива php

Tags: php

```
$mas[0][0] = 'a';
$mas[0][1] = 2;
$mas[1][0] = 'b';
$mas[1][1] = '3';
$mas[2][0] = 'c';
$mas[2][1] = '1';
```

Есть такой массив, как отсортировать по второму, т.е. по $mas[][1], чтобы на выходе было:

```
1:с
2:а
3:b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Позволю себе процитировать этот ответ: [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699159/2486051)

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return ($a[1] - $b[1]);
}

usort($mas, 'sortByOrder');
```

Почитайте документацию к функции [usort](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

> usort — Сортирует массив по значениям используя пользовательскую
>   функцию для сравнения элементов

и [value_compare_func](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php).

> value_compare_func
>   Функция сравнения должна возвращать целое, которое
>   меньше, равно или больше нуля, если первый аргумент является
>   соответственно меньшим, равным или большим чем второй.